# Android M : System permission vs WebView location permission

Tags: android, webview, permissions, callback, location

I have a WebView and some page loaded need the permission for GeolocationPermissions. For that I override onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(). OK.

Also, my app targets SDK 23 (Android M) with the new permissions model. So, I need to check if the user grant the permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and, if not, show a dialog asking the permission.

How to show that dialog only for pages that require the GeolocationPermissions?

The callback onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) is not called.

AndroidManifest:

WebView callbacks

```
@Override
public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
    callback.invoke(origin, true, true);
    super.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin, callback);
}

@Override
public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestLocationPermission();
    else {
        super.onPermissionRequest(request);
    }
```

Show dialog permission

```
private void requestLocationPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
      new ADPDialogFragment(getActivity()) {
        @Override
        public String getTitre() {
            return getString(R.string.mob_he_configuration_dialogue_message_titre);
        }

        @Override
        public String getMessage() {
            return getString(R.string.permission_location_rationale);
        }

        @Override
        public void doPositiveClick() {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }.show(getFragmentManager(), TAG);
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
}
```

Permission callback

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(permission_result)
        // Received permission result for camera permission.
        Log.i(TAG, "Received response for Camera permission request.");

        // Check if the only required permission has been granted
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Camera permission has been granted, preview can be displayed

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.permissions_not_granted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        // END_INCLUDE(permission_result)

    } else {

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you make it work in Android SDK 23? I can't, it's like the callback.invoke does nothing...

Answer (score 4):

You could ask for user's permission when `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` is called:

```
@Override
public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mCallback = callback;
        mOrigin   = origin;
        requestLocationPermission();
    } else {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, true);
    }
}
```

and when the user chooses to grant you the permission or not:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_LOCATION:
        if (mCallback != null && mOrigin != null)
            mCallback.invoke(mOrigin,
                             grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED,
                             false);
        mCallback = null;
        mOrigin   = null;
        break;

    default:
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                                         grantResults);
    }
}
```